# My jquery code is not working inside an ejs template

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ejs

Here is my ejs template which has a jquery in it. Once I click on the done-button it should change the bg-color list item but it's not even coming to that script section.

My ejs is working properly but the jquery inside is troubling me.

Can someone help?

I have tried the same in HTML file and it's working properly .so it makes me think that it's wrong with ejs.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>To-do</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Bhai|Candal|Chewy&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="todo-container">
    <h2>To-do list</h2>
    <div class="todo">
      <form method="POST" action="/add" class="todo-header">
        <input type="text" placeholder="What do you like to do?" name="item" required>
        <button type="submit"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span></button>
      </form>

      <ul class="todo-list">
        <form>
          <% for(var i = 0; i <tasks.length; i++){%>

          <li class="todo-list-item">
            <div class="todo-list-item-name"><%= tasks[i].item %></div>
            <button type="submit" formaction="/remove/<%= tasks[i].id %>" formmethod="post"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> </button>
            <button type="submit" formaction="/edit/<%= tasks[i].id %>" formmethod="get"><i class="fas fa- edit"></i></button>
            <button type="submit" formaction="/done/<%= tasks[i].id %>" formmethod="POST" id="done"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
          </li>
          <br>

          <%} %>

        </form>
      </ul>    
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $("#done").click(function () {
      console.log("I was here")
      $(".todo-list-item ").toggleClass('ButtonClicked');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you also post your css? and maybe delete the unnecessary code to make it more readable and put it in a snippet :)

Comment: .todo-list-item {
                padding: 10px;
                margin-top: 10px;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 5px;
                font-family: 'Candal', sans-serif;
                background:lightgray;                
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                }
  .ButtonClicked {
                                background-color:black;
                            }

Comment: Don't forget to upvote useful answers and accept answers that resolve your question. It costs you nothing and rewards the effort that others have put in to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the code a little bit, but i think this is what your looking for:

```js
$(".done").click(function () {
      $(".todo-list-item").toggleClass('ButtonClicked');
    });
```

```css
.ButtonClicked{
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="todo-list-item">
  <button class="test" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i>btn</button>
  <button class="test" type="submit"><i class="fas fa- edit"></i>btn</button>
  <button class="test done" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up">btn</i></button>
</li>
```

Comment: I want the color to be changed only  when they click on "done button" and that's the reason I have chosen the id for that particular button. But somehow my code is not all going to that portion of script. Whatever the code I have written is correct because I have tested  inside other html file and its working fine

Comment: ok, so you need to change the background-color if you click the "done" button. Which background-color needs to be changed ? the button or the list-item ?

Comment: It's the list-item color  which needs to be changed and this is my code for it:             $( "#done" ).click(function( ) {
console.log("I was here")
$(".todo-list-item ").toggleClass('ButtonClicked');
});

Comment: hm the only wrong thing i see is a single space here: $(".todo-list-item "). But i dont think that causes any problems.. Does your page refresh or redirect after you click the "done" button ?

Comment: Yes it does because I make a post request to done/:id which will update the value as "done" in the database . That's the reason I'm consoling in my script tag on client side to check whether its visiting or not ? nothing is displayed on my browser console which tells me that my jquery is not executing .